# Golang - Range over chan map by key

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm trying to range over channels in a map via key. 
This is the map:

```
documentChansPerHost := make(map[string](chan Document))
```

This is how I want to range over them:

```
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
documentsCountPerHost := make(map[string]int)

// Count documents per host
for _,document := range documents {
    documentsCountPerHost[document.Host]++
}

// Spawn routines for up to 5 times the number of different
for host,documentCount := range documentsCountPerHost {

    println("Spawning " + strconv.Itoa(HOST_CONCURRENCY_LIMIT) + " Routines for Host " + host + " for " + strconv.Itoa(documentCount) + " url(s)")

    for i := 0; i < HOST_CONCURRENCY_LIMIT; i++ {

        go func() {

            for document := range documentChansPerHost[host] {

                fmt.Println(document.Url)
                wg.Done()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's how I create, add and close (to) the channels

```
// Instantiate channels for documents per host
for host,_ := range documentsCountPerHost {
    documentChansPerHost[host] = make(chan Document, 20)
}

for _, document:= range documents {
    wg.Add(1)
    documentChansPerHost[document.Host] <- document
}

for _, documentChan := range documentChansPerHost {
    close(documentChan)
}

wg.Wait()
```

But for some reason it does not output all document Urls I have passed into the channels and the program never ends. Am I using the channel maps in a wrong way or has that something to do with the concurrency and locks somewhere?

Comment: How have you declared `documentsCountPerHost`? And why do you need `documentCount` above if it's not being used? Can you share your full code, complete with how you are working with `WaitGroup`?

Comment: @abhink The counter is used for the comment and the host as key for the channels map. I've added more of my original code to it.

Comment: @KiwiJuicer It is not clear what are you trying to do, please at least aim for One   Compiled Sample Code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: for loop variable `host` should not be used inside `go func()`, because it might change when the goroutine runs.

Comment: @zzn has a very valid point here.  Host is a single variable updated each loop iteration.  You need to capture it inside the goroutine function's argument list in order to ensure you have `host`'s value when the `go func` command is run, since there's no guarantee that the `for range` in the goroutine will run before the outer loop updated `host`.